# Understanding Momentum Conservation of a Fluid in Control Volume

Tags: fluid-dynamics, momentum, conservation-laws, flow

I am taking a course in Fluid Dynamics, and we discussed the conservation of momentum in class:

$$ \dot{M}_{out,x} = \rho u (dydz) u|_{x+dx} + \rho v (dxdz) u|_{x+dx} + \rho v (dxdy) u|_{x+dx} $$

I understand this notation as follows:

$$ \dot{M}_{out,x} = \rho u(x+dx) (dydz) u(x+dx) + \rho v(y) (dxdz) u(x+dx) + \rho w(z) (dxdy) u(x+dx) $$

The next line in the equation on the notes reads:

$$\dot{M}_{out,x} = \rho u (dydz) u + \frac{\partial (\rho u (dydz)u)}{\partial x}dx + \rho v (dydz) u + \frac{\partial (\rho v (dydz)u)}{\partial y}dy + \rho u (dydz) u + \frac{\partial (\rho w (dydz)u)}{\partial z}dz $$

I can see they did a taylor expansion, but since the equation reads $|_{x+dx}$ at every component, I do not understand why the taylor expansion was carried for $|_{y+dy}$ and $|_{z+dz}$.
I am really struggling to arrive to that last form.

Comment: There are presumably still some typos in this question. I think the last "v" on the first line should be a "w". I also struggle to see how one should arrive at the last form given the first form. If you have a link to the lecture notes that could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivation assumes you have a tiny rectangular parallelepiped as our control volume.  It assumes that momentum enters at x, y, and z, and exits at $x+\Delta x$, $y+\Delta y$, and $z+\Delta z$.